# Change the selected item in select input on mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using Bootstrap custom form select input for the users to select country. 
My problem is I have to change the select item in the drop to next item while i scroll the mouse wheel.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/thedon07/k10s427e/)

My code

```
    <select id="inputCountry" class="custom-select">
            <option>Country...</option>
            <option>Afghanistan</option>
            <option>Albania</option>
            <option>Algeria</option>
            <option>American Samoa</option>
            <option>Andorra</option>
            <option>Angola</option>
            <option>Anguilla</option>
            <option>Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
            <option>Argentina</option>
            <option>Armenia</option>
            <option>Aruba</option>
            <option>Australia</option>
            <option>Austria</option>
            <option>Azerbaijan</option>
            <option>Bahamas</option>
            <option>Bahrain</option>
            <option>Bangladesh</option>
            <option>Barbados</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your link does not work. even if stripped, it does not work either.

Comment: please wait i update it

Comment: Fiddle Link is invalid.

Comment: please check now i updated it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: please check now i Updated the link @ Asif

Comment: my question is Now In the above select when i scroll the mouse the selcted item in the option have to change

Comment: You mean: when you scroll the mouse in the page? Even if the select is not focused?

Comment: when I point the select and then i scroll the mouse wheel then the select item has to scroll @Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the focus and if not change `selectedIndex`.

```js
document.getElementById('inputCountry').addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (this.hasFocus) {
        return;
    }
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        this.selectedIndex = Math.max(this.selectedIndex - 1, 0);
    }
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        this.selectedIndex = Math.min(this.selectedIndex + 1, this.length - 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="inputCountry" class="custom-select">
  <option>Country...</option>
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
  <option>Albania</option>
  <option>Algeria</option>
  <option>American Samoa</option>
  <option>Andorra</option>
  <option>Angola</option>
  <option>Anguilla</option>
  <option>Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
  <option>Argentina</option>
  <option>Armenia</option>
  <option>Aruba</option>
  <option>Australia</option>
  <option>Austria</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Bahamas</option>
  <option>Bahrain</option>
  <option>Bangladesh</option>
  <option>Barbados</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks . Does this one done by only using CSS or else by bootstrap ?

Comment: It should be `this.length-1` instead of `this.length`